# subtract from values by groups

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the best way to subtract the lowest value from all values by group?

Something like:

```
ID    Name         Value    
1      A             10    
1      B             40    
1      C             100    
2      A             20     
2      B             80    
2      C             90    
3      A             4    
3      B             7    
3      C             8
```

turn to:

```
ID    Name         Value    
1      A             0    
1      B             30    
1      C             90    
2      A             0     
2      B             60    
2      C             70    
3      A             0
3      B             3    
3      C             4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select id, name, value - min(value) over (partition by id) as 
from t;
```

If you actually want to update the values, in MySQL, aggregation and `join` are probably the simplest solution:

```
update t join
       (select id, min(value) as min_value
        from t
        group by id
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.id
    set value = value - min_value
    where min_value <> 0;
```